# upload large files to blob storage without saving file locally mean stack

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

Currently I am able to upload files to blob storage by saving the file locally. But I want to stream the file directly to storage. as I am completely new to filesystem I am not able to do it using createReadStrem(filepath) as it is expecting file path and on search I got to see that its not possible to get the path from front end. I was dividing the file in to chunks and writing to stream. if anyone can help me with any way to do it?

```
Headers:
X-Chunk-Id: 0
X-Content-Id: a997d61859d6d3814d5f3f4a..
x-Content-Length: 19

payload:
fdfdfgytuujftyeeyjh    // hi.txt dummyfiledata it can be zip file also
```

API

```
const fs = require("fs");
function uploadToBlob(request, response) {
const chunkComplete = file.pushChunk(chunkId, chunk, chunkSize);
const size = file.getChunkLength(chunkId);
if (file.isCompleted()) {
var userrole = file.userrole;
var projectId = file.id;
var projectname = file.path;
var fileName = file.name;
var blobName = projectname + '/' + file.name;
var sourceFilePath = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
const fstream = fs.createReadStrem(sourceFilePath);
let chunks = file.getContent(); 
for (let j = 0; j < chunks.length; j++)
{
fstream.write(chunks[j]);
}
fstream.end();
delete fileStorage[fileId];
fstream.on("finish", () => {
// bs.createBlockBlobFromLocalfile( file gets saved to blob storage)
//Instead i want to use  bs.createBlockBlobFromstream() here and stream directly to blob without saving locally
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog](https://www.carbonatethis.com/streaming-files-to-azure-blob-storage-with-node-js/) shows you how to streaming files to Azure Blob Storage with Node.js.

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.on('part', function(part) {
        if (part.filename) {
            var filename = part.filename;
            var size = part.byteCount;

            var onError = function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    res.send({ grrr: error });
                }
            };
            blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('container', filename, part, size, onError);
        } else {
            form.handlePart(part);
        }
    });

    form.parse(req);
    res.send("SWEET");
});
```

Convert buffer into stream with **Readable** method. like this:

```
const stream = Readable.from(buffer); 
blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('container-name', 'filename', stream, buffer.byteLength, function(error, response) {         
    if (error) {             
        console.log('Error!');             
        console.log(error);         
    } else {             
        console.log('Blob uploaded successfully!');             
        console.log(response);         
    }     
});
```

Comment: I have the data in buffer so i want to convert it into stream and pass the arg to method.here is the code m trying     var myReadableStreamBuffer = new streamBuffers.ReadableStreamBuffer({
//    frequency: 10, chunkSize: size     
});
  myReadableStreamBuffer.put(c);
 blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName, blobName, myReadableStreamBuffer,10, err => {

Comment: error: 'Required argument callback for function _createBlobFromStream is not defined''ArgumentNullError'

Comment: Please try to convert buffer into stream with `Readable` method. like this: `const stream = Readable.from(buffer); blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('container-name', 'filename', stream, buffer.byteLength, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error!');
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Blob uploaded successfully!');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });`

Comment: I edit my reply with this error, you could accept it, thank you.